# $EUID is empty in /etc/init.d/celeryd

Tags: celery, root, daemon, worker

I'm trying to configure the celery worker as a daemon as per
[Running the worker as a daemon](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/tutorials/daemonizing.html#running-the-worker-as-a-daemon).

Even though I work directly from *root* I can't run the service since the **$EUID is empty** and thus the condition

```
if [ "$EUID" != "0" ]; then
    echo "Error: This program can only be used by the root user."
    exit 1
fi
```

is always true.

This happens only when I try to run the service.

```
echo $EUID
```

in the console naturally prints 0.

What's the reason of this behavior? How to solve it to make the celery worker run as a daemon?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1804) is corresponding issue.